# How to remove a column with the same contents?

Tags: xml, xslt

i need to remove and identify a column with all the same values.
The given XML is something like this:

```
<PRODTABLE>
    <PRODTR>
        <PRODTD>H1</PRODTD>
        <PRODTD>H2</PRODTD>
        <PRODTD>H3</PRODTD>
        <PRODTD>Headline 6</PRODTD>
        <PRODTD blacklist="1">Head 7</PRODTD>
        <PRODTD>Head 8</PRODTD>
        <PRODTD blacklist="1">Test</PRODTD>
    </PRODTR>
    <PRODTR>
        <PRODTD>7.5</PRODTD>
        <PRODTD>95mm</PRODTD>
        <PRODTD>WHATEVERTEXT</PRODTD>
        <PRODTD>Lorem</PRODTD>
        <PRODTD blacklist="1">Foobar</PRODTD>
        <PRODTD>TEST</PRODTD>
        <PRODTD blacklist="1">011601100</PRODTD>
    </PRODTR>
    <PRODTR>
        <PRODTD>9</PRODTD>
        <PRODTD>92mm</PRODTD>
        <PRODTD>WHATEVERTEXT</PRODTD>
        <PRODTD>Lorem</PRODTD>
        <PRODTD blacklist="1">Foobar</PRODTD>
        <PRODTD>TEST</PRODTD>
        <PRODTD blacklist="1">021063100</PRODTD>
    </PRODTR>
</PRODTABLE>
```

After running it through my stylesheet it should yield to this result:

```
    <PRODTABLE>
    <PRODTR>
        <PRODTD>H1</PRODTD>
        <PRODTD>H2</PRODTD>
        <PRODTD blacklist="1">Head 7</PRODTD>
        <PRODTD blacklist="1">Test</PRODTD>
    </PRODTR>
    <PRODTR>
        <PRODTD>7.5</PRODTD>
        <PRODTD>95mm</PRODTD>
        <PRODTD blacklist="1">Foobar</PRODTD>
        <PRODTD blacklist="1">011601100</PRODTD>
    </PRODTR>
    <PRODTR>
        <PRODTD>9</PRODTD>
        <PRODTD>92mm</PRODTD>
        <PRODTD blacklist="1">Foobar</PRODTD>
        <PRODTD blacklist="1">021063100</PRODTD>
    </PRODTR>
</PRODTABLE>
```

So all equal cells in a column are removed (see `WHATEVERTEXT`, `Lorem`, `TEST` from the source XML).
I already managed to exlcude the columns which are blacklisted. The blacklisted columns should (even tho they might be equal) be ignored.

This is my empty template to match all duplicates and just do nothing with it.

```
<xsl:template match="PRODTD[ not(
    for $c in count(preceding-sibling::PRODTD)+1 return
      ../../PRODTR/PRODTD[$c][. = //*/PRODTR[2]/PRODTD[$c]]) and
    @blacklist != 1]"/>
```

An this prints the result for all leftover or blacklisted cells.

```
<xsl:template match="PRODTD[ 
    for $c in count(preceding-sibling::PRODTD)+1 return
      ../../PRODTR/PRODTD[$c][. = //*/PRODTR[2]/PRODTD[$c]] or
    @blacklist = 1]">

    [...]

</xsl:template>
```

My current current result only prints the blacklisted columns.

I already used that solution [xslt remove table column when all specific value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12206179/xslt-remove-table-column-when-all-specific-value)
but failed to adjust it to match all other columns entries instead of '-'.

Hint: before and after that Table `PRODTABLE` can be more XML elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a key helps, in XSLT 3 (supported with .NET and Java by Saxon 9.8 HE or higher) you can use a composite key:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:key name="col-index-value"
    match="PRODTABLE/PRODTR[position() gt 1]/PRODTD[not(@blacklist = 1)]"
    composite="yes"
    >
      <xsl:variable name="pos" as="xs:integer">
          <xsl:number/>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:sequence select="$pos, string()"/>
  </xsl:key>

  <xsl:template match="PRODTABLE/PRODTR[1]/PRODTD[let $pos := position() return count(key('col-index-value', (position(), ../../PRODTR[2]/PRODTD[$pos]), ancestor::PRODTABLE)) = (count(ancestor::PRODTABLE/PRODTR) - 1)]"/>
  <xsl:template 
    match="PRODTABLE/PRODTR[position() gt 1]/PRODTD[not(@blacklist = 1) and count(key('col-index-value', (position(), string()), ancestor::PRODTABLE)) = (count(ancestor::PRODTABLE/PRODTR) - 1)]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6rexjhU

Or it should simply suffice to compute and count the distinct values and based on that count, passed on as a tunnel parameter, eliminate the col:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="PRODTABLE">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:variable name="count-col-values"
            select="let $rows := PRODTR[position() > 1]
                    return
                    for $pos in 1 to count($rows[1]/PRODTD)
                    return count(distinct-values($rows/PRODTD[$pos]))"/>
          <xsl:apply-templates>
              <xsl:with-param name="count-col-values" select="$count-col-values" tunnel="yes"/>
          </xsl:apply-templates>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="PRODTD[not(@blacklist = 1)]">
      <xsl:param name="count-col-values" tunnel="yes"/>
      <xsl:if test="subsequence($count-col-values, position(), 1) > 1">
          <xsl:next-match/>
      </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6rexjhU/1

It seems that could also be simplified to simply pass on the column indices of the columns not all having the same value:

```
  <xsl:template match="PRODTABLE">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:variable name="positions"
            select="let $rows := PRODTR[position() > 1]
                    return
                    for $pos in 1 to count($rows[1]/PRODTD)
                    return $pos[count(distinct-values($rows/PRODTD[$pos])) > 1]"/>
          <xsl:apply-templates>
              <xsl:with-param name="positions" select="$positions" tunnel="yes"/>
          </xsl:apply-templates>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="PRODTD[not(@blacklist = 1)]">
      <xsl:param name="positions" tunnel="yes"/>
      <xsl:if test="$positions = position()">
          <xsl:next-match/>
      </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6rexjhU/2

Comment: Works like a charm! I used the last version you provided since this felt like the most intuitive solution to me.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to look at it:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:key name="col" match="PRODTD" use="index-of(../PRODTD, .)" />

<xsl:template match="PRODTD[not(.!=key('col', index-of(../PRODTD, .)))]"/>
```

---

Demo: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFWRAoY

---

This could be made more efficient by running the test on the cells of first row only and storing the results in a variable - then using this to exclude the cells in the column numbers stored in the variable.